# Increase number of seconds in the time interval in system monitor

Tags: gnome, system-monitor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 BIT OS.
My **Gnome-System-Monitor** shows the graph for **only for last 15 seconds,** I want make it to **show graph for 60 seconds**. How to make this change.

Note: Other Linux OS in my PC is showing 60 seconds graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily restore your 60 seconds graph by opening the System Monitor Preferences menu:

[image]

Open the Resources Tab and set the interval to 1,00 as shown below:

[image]

Or from the command line:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor/graph-update-interval 1000
```

Comment: It seems that on the Bionic version it doesn't go beyond 100.00 s.

Answer (score 0):

On 16.04 the top line *System Monitor* menu is only available when the window is maximised.

```
    dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor/graph-update-interval 10000
```

Changes the config as can be seen with:

```
    dconf dump /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor/
```

*[/]*

*current-tab='resources'*

*show-whose-processes='user'*

*window-state=(1293, 741, 73, 27)*

***graph-update-interval=10000***

***maximized=true***

*show-dependencies=false*